# How to use a torque wrench when there is no room for it?

Tags: torque, bolts, peugeot-405, peugeot-406

In my car, the space between idler and tensioner bearing bolts and the chassis is so limited (as per the following picture) that you can't use a torque wrench. In fact, the torque wrench itself can be put in the area but you can't attach any socket to it. I had to use a ring spanner to tighten the bolts but first, I practiced with my torque wrench to get the feeling of the required torque specs (with other bolts on the car) to avoid over-tightening the bolts.
Is there anyway to use a torque wrench in my next service?
[image]

Comment: I've taken a socket and ground the length down to fit into such spaces.  I know there are some "stubby" sockets on the market but they tend to be expensive.

Comment: I would apply basic physics: Torque = Force *  Distance, so take a spanner of x length which fits and pull with y force... Simple, just need to understand what you are doing.

Comment: You can also get a narrow "break over" torque wrench such as [here](https://www.mountztorque.com/Product-Type/Torque-Wrenches/Torque-Wrenches-Break-Over-Wrenches/Torque-Wrenches-Break-Over-Wrenches-TB). The elbow folds when torque is exceeded.

Comment: @Weather Vane - I didn't even know such a tool exists!! That was a great idea!!

Comment: Have you checked to see if you can access this area through the fender well? If so, an extension used properly will accurately allow you to torque these bolts.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - Yes, I have tried reaching the bolts through the fender. I even removed upper engine mount bracket and jacked the engine up and down to improve access but none of them helped!

Comment: Which car/engine do you have?  If you tell us, someone may know how you get access.

Comment: @HandyHowie  - This car (Peugeot) has only been made in my area (Asia). It is neither 405 nor 406. It is a facelifted Peugeot 405 with the engine taken from 406! This is why the engine has occupied most of its engine bay.

Comment: @Solar Mike - That technique is helpful but not for this case. I can't attach a hanging scale to a ring spanner for measuring force.

Comment: You need to change “I can’t…” to “I can try…”.

Comment: Try using a piece of string between spanner and scale…

Comment: @Solar Mike - The problem is that my scale works accurately when I hold it upright. Otherwise, I don't get an accurate reading.

Comment: Perhaps you don't know how the scale works - usually the spring is rated to give the correct reading. So test it by mounting the scale horizontally and use a pulley with a bag of sugar as a known mass... Just need to understand the principles involved, not " I can't" again.

Comment: @Solar Mike - Do you mean I have to calibrate my scale to use it horizontally? According to my measurements, when I hold it horizontally, I get about 500 grams less than the actual weight. So, if I need 3 kg of weight (force), I have to apply 3.5 kg. Is this what you mean?